# Search data in data table by passing ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to search a data from data data table in JavaScript or jquery. i have a data table in my JS here i want to select a record on ID one way is loop on data table and go through all datatable rows but it become slow when i have large number of data i want to implement select in JavaScript like C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the id directly in the selector:

```
var vId = '123';
$('#d'+vId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you hit a performance problem? If it is, you may can simplify your tr/td structure to div block

```
<div class="table">
<div class="row">
<div class="col">Data 1</div>
<div class="col">Data 2</div>
<div class="col">Data 3</div>
</div>
</div>
```

or you can try to move the key to data attribute to reduce the search effort of Jquery. It will save you for a lot of layout problem.

```
  <table>
        <tr data-key="001">
        <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-key="002">
        <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-key="003">
        <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: i have to implement a search on data table not a html table